# clang compiling error (undefined reference to objc_autoreleasepoolpush)

Tags: objective-c, clang, gnustep

So, I got Ubuntu and clang3.0 installed and a simple program.m:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{
        @autoreleasepool{
            NSLog(@"Hi");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

and I try to compile it like this:

```
clang first.m -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -objc
```

and I get

```
undefined reference to objc_autoreleasePoolPush
undefined reference to objc_autoreleasePoolPop
```

so I've googled a little and install objc2 and tried:

```
clang first.m -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -objc2
```

but nothing changes. Maybe someone had same problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With libobjc2 installed on my Ubuntu system, a copy of your first.m files compiles for me with this line:

```
clang first.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --objc-libs` \
-I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -lgnustep-base
```

but maybe it is simply a typo at the end of your command lines?

The -objc at the end of your first example and the -objc2 at the end of the second are instructing the clang compiler to create executables with names bjc and bjc2, respectively.  Did you mean -lobj?  I think linking in the obj library is critical for getting an Objective-C runtime library.  Even with the libobjc2 project, the library produced is still named libobjc.so.x.y.  If your command doesn't include a -lobjc, I don't see how it could ever link correctly.  I could be wrong but it doesn't work for me without it.

Comment: thanks WeakPointer )

clang first.m `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --objc-libs` -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -lgnustep-base -I /home/nazar/libobjc2/

this works fine but I get warning: argument unused during compilation: '-shared-libgcc'


thanks again )

Comment: and now I get warning: libobjc.so.3, needed by /usr/lib/libgnustep-base.so, may conflict with libobjc.so.4

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this applies to GNUstep, but on OS X you have to add the `-fobjc-arc` compiler flag if you want to compile with ARC.

Comment: According to http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ, you have to add the `-fobjc-nonfragile-abi` option.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build it with GNUmakefile?

Here's how to write one.

http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/node2.html

One could be compiled and linked like

clang first.m -c -MMD -MP -DGNUSTEP -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_GUI_LIBRARY=1 -DGNU_RUNTIME=1 -DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 -fobjc-runtime=gnustep-1.7 -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -fobjc-exceptions -D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS -fobjc-nonfragile-abi -D_NONFRAGILE_ABI -pthread -fPIC -DDEBUG -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -DGSWARN -DGSDIAGNOSE -Wno-import -g -fgnu-runtime -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -I. -I/usr/local/include -o obj/first.obj/first.m.o

clang -rdynamic -pthread -shared-libgcc -fexceptions -fobjc-nonfragile-abi -fgnu-runtime -o obj/first ./obj/first.obj/first.m.o -L/usr/local/lib -lgnustep-base -lobjc -lm

Depending on how you configure the GNUstep make package.

Comment: Huh? What has the makefile got to do with the OP's linker issue?

Comment: It is not just a makefile, it's a makefile that include configured options. GNUstep make package usually provide the options that was used to build the GNUstep libraries, includingn linker options.